# MS PowerPoint CheckBox remains linked when slide is duplicated

Tags: checkbox, duplicates, powerpoint

Hoping you can help me as I have searched a lot of forums and did not find the same question, never mind the answer I need :) 
I have a power point pack which I have put together. It is built to be a template for my team to use repeatedly and is set up using slide masters to control the layout. Each layout slide in the slide master includes two checkboxes to identify either a pass or a fail. My problem is that when you insert a new slide (by either duplicating an existing slide or adding a slide from the slide master layout), and change the checkbox value it also changes on the other slide. Is there a way either using some quick VBA or otherwise to stop this from happening and break the link between the two slides. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a weird way, this is reasonable behavior from PowerPoint, though it certainly does seem bizarre.

Shapes on a master layout appear on any slide based on that layout. Though they appear on the slide, they're not editable on the slide; it's as though the slide were a clear layer above the layout, one that you can add more stuff to but that you can't "penetrate" to get at the stuff on the layout below.

Placeholders are a special case and so, apparently, are ActiveX controls like your checkboxes, which DO allow editing.  So what's happening is that when you change a text box, you're changing the text box on the layout, not on the slide itself (the checkbox doesn't even exist on the slide ... you can't select and move it in normal view, for example, unless you go to the layout in Master view).

When you change the checkbox, you're changing the one on the layout, and since the checkboxes appear on any slide based on the layout, when you change the checkbox, you're changing the one on the layout, ALL of the slides based on that layout get the changed checkboxes.

Some mildly tricky VBA could look at each slide and if it's based on the layout that contains the checkboxes, COPY them to the current slide from the layout and finally make the checkboxes on the layout invisible.

The simpler solution might be to supply a sample slide with the checkboxes ON the slide and let the users copy/paste it into their presentations.

[later]
I've reported this to MS as not so much a bug as a design oversight; the behavior may make sense, but it's not useful and can mislead users (as you well know).

I'd suggest that you visit https://powerpoint.uservoice.com and suggest that ActiveX objects on masters/layouts behave more like placeholders ... spawn new instances of themselves when a new slide based on the layout is added rather than letting the user THINK that's what's happened.